# eas ios build fails with error you must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE)

Tags: react-native, build, expo, eas

I'm trying to build my react-native expo (46) app with an eas build and get this error:

```
ld: '/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/.../FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' for architecture arm64
```

saying that I must enable Xcode setting `ENABLE_BITCODE`.

Is there any way to give this settinh in `eas.json` or `app.json`?

Comment: it looks like FBAEMKit doesn't support bitcode. bitcode was also deprecated in xcode 14, there is no need to use it. you can disable bitcode on your project: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#bitcode

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna answer to myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments by @brentvatne it's a problem with FBAEMKit that is used by [react-native-fbsdk-next](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/331) (I use the version `11.0.1`)

I was able to get rid of the problem adding

```
"bitcode": "Debug"
```

in `app.json` under in the `ios` part.

(Please note that my IDE gave me an error but it was still valid and I'm now able to build my app)